# Search function using filter and hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to follow an react-course on udemy but am using hooks instead of classes and states as the instructor shows. It is an simple app where I download random userinfo and images and shows them using flash-cards.

Then I need to be able to search/filter the users. I have managed to get this working by using two different useEffects but I would like to know if this is the correct way to solve this. And also if I can get any tips on how to improve my current code.

[Project on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/23hnw)

Comment: You can wrap onChangeHandler in App in a useCallback. Wrap your functional components in a React.memo. But other than that I don't see obvious errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK. However you don't need to use the second useEffect. you can compute filter directly in the functions body. If you want to cache the results you can use useMemo hook but it's unnecessary here.

Basically what I would do is:

```js
const filter = users && users.length ? users.filter((person) =>
        person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      ); || []
```